# Need to store users infos in a faster way into Redis, what are the right commands to use ? (To get better performances)

Tags: php, redis, redis-cluster

I need to store users infos, and looking for the right way to do it !

Knowing that this are the infos to store in:

```
- Addresses
- Full Name
- Phone number
- Location
```

This infos, can be changed by the user on demand from an HTML form.

### What I need ?

The right way to store this infos inside Redis server and update them in a faster way !

### What I tried ?

1- First I store all infos inside JSON array

2- Store the JSON array using this command (SET):

```
$redis->set('user:8:infos', json_encode($infos));  
// And set expiration ...
```

### Updating infos

And then In order to update the infos:
1- First get the key:

`$infos = $redis->get('user:8:infos');`

2- Deserialize the JSON array

3- Modify the right key and value of the JSON array

4- Serialize the JSON array

5- update it again into Redis using SET command like we are inserting it for first time

You can see that there many operation to do in order to update one info of the user and this take many ressources from server especially if we have big traffic.

I need the right way (Faster and to get better performances) to manage users infos and manipulate them inside Redis server.

I read somewhere on the official redis website that "Sorted sets" are fastest than others ?

Your answer will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your user info is simple, e.g. no nested structure, the best and fast way to save user info is Redis `HASH`:

```
// SET
HSET user1 address XXX
HSET user1 full-name XXX
HSET user1 phone-number XXX
HSET user1 location XXX

// GET single field
HGET user1 address

// UPDATE single field
HSET user1 full-name YYY
```

However, if your user info is complex, and have nested structure, e.g. *{"addr" : "xxx", "location" : {"latitude" : 12.3, "longitude" : "23.4"}}*, you can use [RedisJSON](https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON) or [redis-protobuf](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-protobuf) to save the user info. So that you can get or update a single field with better performance.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer sir ! Is there a way to store all the infos using only one command ? Instead of using 4 calls to redis? For RedisJSON, is it faster than HSET/HGET or slower at updating datas espacially if I want to update one key ? Thank's again.

Comment: What about using ZADD for infos that contain DECIMALs ? HSET vs ZADD who is fast ? (`ZADD user:8 9955644221 phone-number`)

Comment: @CliffAnger 1. You can use `HMSET` command to set all your user info into a HASH. 2. You should do some benchmark to test which one is faster. 3. IMHO, in your case, `HASH` is better, also, in theory, `HSET` should be faster than `ZADD`. Since with `ZADD` needs to update 2 indexes, while `HSET` only update 1 index.

Comment: Thank you sir :) appreciated.